# Doctrine: No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias() error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My Original Query is:

```
Select * from user u
inner join company c
on u.company_id = c.id 
where u.id=2
```

And I made it as:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb->select('u')
            ->from('TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\Entity\User u')
            ->innerjoin('u.company')
            ->where('u.id = ' . $id);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $result = $query->getResult();
```

I get 500 with following details in Log:

> [2016-09-27 12:06:34] request.INFO: Matched route
>   "templatemanager_documentgenerator_api_client_find" (parameters:
>   "_controller":
>   "TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\Controller\API\ClientController::findAction",
>   "id": "2", "_route":
>   "templatemanager_documentgenerator_api_client_find") [] []
>    > [2016-09-27 12:06:34] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the
>   session [] []
>    > [2016-09-27 12:06:34] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user
>   provider. [] []
>    > [2016-09-27 12:06:34] security.DEBUG: Username "admin" was reloaded
>   from user provider. [] []
>    > [2016-09-27 12:06:34] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   RuntimeException: "No alias was set before invoking getRootAlias()."
>   at //myproject//vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php
>   line 423 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No alias
>   was set before invoking getRootAlias(). at
>   //myproject//vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php:423)"}
>   []
>    > [2016-09-27 12:06:34] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the
>   session [] []

Answer (score 0):

try this
add the alias on $em->createQueryBuilder();

```
$em->createQueryBuilder('u');
```

by the way prepare your query to avoid sql injection

```
$qb->select('u')
  ->from('User', 'u')
  ->where('u.id = ?1')
  ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC')
  ->setParameter(1, 100);
```

On my own project I tried this and it works well:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('u');

$qb->select('u')
        ->from('INSIDE\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\TAdminUser', 'u')
        ->innerJoin('u.idUser' , 'myalias')
        ->where('u.idAdminUser = 2');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->getResult();
```

idUser is another table not an id we had migration problems :)

Comment: It's a join one

Comment: What do you mean by it's a join one ?

Comment: The query I need is the SQL JOIN. Check Original Query

Comment: I tryed this and it works:
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('u');
        $qb->select('u')
            ->from('INSIDE\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\TAdminUser', 'u')
            ->innerJoin('u.idUser' , 'myalias')
            ->where('u.idAdminUser = :ua_id')
            ->setParameter('ua_id', 2);

I added ->from('INSIDE\Bundle\AdminBundle\Entity\TAdminUser', 'u')

Comment: Edit main answer pls?

Comment: On latest versions of Doctrine do not handle any param in `createQueryBuilder()`.
I fixed this issue by adding the missing `from(Entity::class, 'e')`.

Answer (score 0):

The `->from()` needs a second parameter, so your code would look like:

```
$qb->select('u')
   ->from('TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\Entity\User', 'u')
```

And better yet, you could use `User::class` like this:

```
use TemplateManager\Bundle\DocumentGeneratorBundle\Entity\User;

...

$qb->select('u')
   ->from(User::class, 'u')
```